# cat files based on substring match

Tags: bash, cat

I have file names in the following format and I would like to cat files based on substring match(Orange,Apple) and a constant(S4,S5),

file names example `_S6_trimmed_, _S8_trimmed_, _S9_trimmed_, _S10_trimmed_`

```
Orange1_S4_trimmed_1.fastq
Orange1_S4_trimmed_2.fastq
Orange2_S4_trimmed_1.fastq
Orange2_S4_trimmed_2.fastq

Apple1_S4_trimmed_1.fastq
Apple1_S4_trimmed_2.fastq
Apple2_S4_trimmed_1.fastq
Apple2_S4_trimmed_2.fastq

Orange1_S5_trimmed_1.fastq
Orange1_S5_trimmed_2.fastq
Orange2_S5_trimmed_1.fastq
Orange2_S5_trimmed_2.fastq

Apple1_S5_trimmed_1.fastq
Apple1_S5_trimmed_2.fastq
Apple2_S5_trimmed_1.fastq
Apple2_S5_trimmed_2.fastq
```

What I want to do and repeat the same for several samples S4, S5,..

```
cat Orange*_S4_trimmed_1.fastq >Orange_S4_trimmed_1.fastq
cat Orange*_S4_trimmed_2.fastq >Orange_S4_trimmed_2.fastq

cat Apple*_S4_trimmed_1.fastq >Apple_S4_trimmed_1.fastq
cat Apple*_S4_trimmed_2.fastq >Apple_S4_trimmed_2.fastq
```

Here is a script I wrote in bash,

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="samples.txt"

while read -r sample;
do
    echo $sample
    cat ${sample}_trimmed_1.fastq >${sample}_trimmed_1.fastq
    cat ${sample}_trimmed_2.fastq >${sample}_trimmed_2.fastq

done <$filename
```

Here is the format for my samples.txt file,

```
 samples.txt
 Apple*_S4
 Apple*_S5
 Orange*_S4
 Orange*_S5
```

Is there a better way to do this on a large group of files? Thanks for your help in advance.

A solution I'm currently working on based on comments on Bodo,

```
#!/bin/bash
    
    for file in *1_*_trimmed_1.fastq;
    do
        echo $file
    
        subs=`echo $file | cut -d_ -f1 | tr -d 0-9`
        echo $subs
    
        sample=`echo $file | cut -d_ -f2`
        echo $sample
    
        cat ${subs}*_${sample}_trimmed_1.fastq >${subs}_${sample}_trimmed_1.fastq
        cat ${subs}*_${sample}_trimmed_2.fastq >${subs}_${sample}_trimmed_2.fastq
    
    done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do the groups of files that should be concatenated always have one file with number `1` (and others with `2` and maybe more numbers) for the placeholder `*`as in `Apple*_S4_trimmed_1.fastq`? In this case my suggestion would be a loop over all files with `1` and construct the corresponding concatenation command.

Comment: Yes, the place holder(*) will be 1 or 2.

Comment: Please add this to your question.

Comment: Please add what's not working with the solution based on my comment. Specify in your question if the file names always contain `_S4_trimmed_` or `_S5_trimmed_` or show a longer list of example file names. This might help to propose commands to construct the file names. Better use `$( ... )` instead of backticks for command substitution.

Comment: Side note: you may get away with not quoting here, but sooner or later it will bite you. Get used to [quoting properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Comment: Are you sure you want to **overwrite** the result file at every hit, so only the last one will persist? — Else, if you want to **append** their content, you should use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: The above code works based on comments from @Bodo. I have also provided a longer list of file names. Would this be a better way?

subs="$(echo $file | cut -d_ -f1 | tr -d 0-9)"
sample="$(echo $file | cut -d_ -f2)"

Answer (score 1):

###### 1. Paste all source files to their destination

As in your question the sample code all files of a file set get pasted to their destination file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

destination=""

# Select all source files, but not any existing the destination files:
for file in *[0-9]*_S[0-9]*_trimmed_*[0-9].fastq
do  
    if [ "${destination}" != "${file%%[0-9]*}_${file#*_}" ]
    then
        # Switch to next file set:
        destination="${file%%[0-9]*}_${file#*_}"
        echo "${destination}"
    fi
    # Copy the current source file to destination
    cat "${file}" >"${destination}"
done
```

This is almost only useful for **named pipes** as destination files which will transfer the received data elsewhere.

---

###### 2. Paste only the last source file to its destination

If the destination is a regular file writing all source files to destination would be a tremendous overhead, as the content gets overwritten every time, just leaving the latest version to persist.

This second solution prohibits the overhead and minimizes the amount of data that will be written:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

destination=""
source=""

# Select all source files, but not any existing the destination files:
for file in *[0-9]*_S[0-9]*_trimmed_*[0-9].fastq
do  
    if [ "${destination}" != "${file%%[0-9]*}_${file#*_}" ]
    then
        if [ "${destination}" != "" ]
        then
            # Not the start situation. Write last file of file set to the destination file:
            cat "${source}" >"${destination}"
        fi
        # Switch to next file set:
        destination="${file%%[0-9]*}_${file#*_}"
        echo ${destination}
    fi
    # Store the current source file name for the next cycle
    source=${file}
done
# Write last source file of the last file set to the destination, if it exists:
if [ "${destination}" != "" ]
then
    cat "${source}" >"${destination}"
fi
```

As you used `cat`for your file duplication I used it, too. But usually one would use `cp` instead.
So one would exchange the line `cat "${file}" >"${destination}"` by

```
cp "${file}" "${destination}"
```

If source- or destination-files are not subject of editing anymore, one should think about creating a hard-link. So there would be no duplication of data at all (not extra disk usage by the destination file). Only the destination filename would be created, pointing to the same data area (inode) as the selected source file:

```
cp -l --remove-destination "${file}" "${destination}"
```

For huge files (like video data) this would be a great speed up.

Comment: Answer updated: Added a second version of the script to cover the use-case of named pipes. // Fixed an error in the original script.

Comment: Did this solve your question ?